# Phone numbers to search irrespective of the format stored in Database

Tags: apex, soql, dynamic-soql

I have the requirement where I need to search a phone number in the UI like => 8405678978. So if I am passing the number in the UI like this 8405678978, it is not querying from the database as in the database it will be stored in the following format ==> (840) 567-8978 or 840-567-8978.

Below is the way I have tried in the dynamic query.

```
if (searchstring != null) {
    String tmpsearchstring = searchstring+'%';
    String tmpPhoneString='%'+searchstring+'%'; 
    System.debug(tmpPhoneString);
    queryString += ' AND (FirstName like :tmpsearchstring OR LastName like :tmpsearchstring OR Name like :tmpsearchstring OR EMail like :tmpsearchstring OR Phone like :tmpPhoneString)';
```

The problem I am facing is if in the UI I pass 840 (only 3 digits) then all other phone numbers with 840 as there middle digits or last digits are showing up....and if I pass a phone number as 8405 (4 digits) then record is not displaying because of the format of phone number stored in database. How can I get the records even if I pass 4 digits or 5 digits in the search box?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a custom text field for each standard phone field you want to search, then create a process builder or a workflow on each standard field to strip out parentheses, dashes, and spaces and paste the stripped number into the custom field.

A quick Google search turned up [this formula](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000h0fEAAQ) in the Salesforce Success community.  You can modify it for use in your workflow or Process Builder:

```
SUBSTITUTE( 
    SUBSTITUTE( 
        SUBSTITUTE( 
            SUBSTITUTE(
                Phone, "(", ""
            ), ")", ""
        ), " ", ""
    ), "-", ""
)
```

Comment: You might want to also substitute the `.` character, as some people might input in the format `###.###.####` (or other similar formats depending on nationality).